# Grok learning: Letters in the letterbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, grok

I am trying to write a code that will let a user input a name, then read a file and show how much mail that person has.

file called mail.txt

```
Jane Fairfax,Letter
Frank Churchill,Letter
Emma Woodhouse,Letter
Frank Churchill,Letter
Harriet Smith,Package
Emma Woodhouse,Letter
Philip Elton,Package
Emma Woodhouse,Package
```

The program should work like this:

```
Name: Emma Woodhouse
2 Letters
1 Package
```

if they have 1 package and 2 letters,

```
Name: Jane Fairfax
1 Letter
No Packages
```

if they have 1 letter and no package, and if the person doesn't have any mail, your program should work like this:

```
Name: Elizabeth Bennet
No mail
```

This is my code so far (which doesn't work)

```
name = input('Name: ')
mail = open('mail.txt')
m = mail.readlines()
l = ''
ln = 0 
p = []
pn= 0 
for line in m:
  if name in line:
    l= line.split(',')
    if l[1] == 'Letter':
      ln= ln+1
    else:
      pn = pn+1
print(str(ln) + ' Letters\n' + str(pn) + ' Packages')
```

and this is what it returns:

```
Name: Emma Woodhouse
0 Letters
3 Packages
```

I am struggling with this one and I haven't even started adding the extra elements in!!!
I will keep working on it but some help/input would be greatly appreciated!  (I think I might have to use a (def) but I'm not sure...)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `l[1]` contains a new line character. If you print it you'll see that it == 'Letter\n' and thus is not equal to 'Letter'.

You could `.strip()` your line or l[1] or use `if 'Letter' in l[1]` to make it white space tolerant.

Since it doesn't match 'Letter' it always goes into the else (package) block. You should probably test for package explicitly and have the else clause as an unknown, exception case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution on how to do it:

```
import collections

mail = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open('mail.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    person, item = line.strip().split(',')
    mail[person].append(item)

person = input('Name: ')
if person not in mail:
  print('No mail')
else:
  for item in ('Letter', 'Package'):
    count = mail[person].count(item)
    if count == 0:
      print('No', item + 's')
    elif count == 1:
      print(1, item)
    else:
      print(count, item + 's')
```

This is also a solution that Grok Learning approves.